# Is it possible to get the email of the purpose making an in-app purchase in your app?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to get the email of the purpose making an in-app purchase in your app?

Comment: I do not think so, and I hope so, why should you get it? The customer pays you to get something, not to give you his email id.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app have an account system? When the user makes a purchase if you have an account system you can trigger an event to your server to store that persons email (since you presumably would have it in the account system/store on your app).